# MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms from Next.js application

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I'm encountering the "MongooseError: Operation users.findOne() Buffering Timed Out After 10000ms" error in my Next.js application. I'm using Mongoose (^8.2.2) to connect to a MongoDB database.

I'm using Next.js 14+

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified the MongoDB connection string is accurate and includes all credentials.
Confirmed the MongoDB server is running and accessible.
I changed acces IP to anywhere. And The error occurs consistently.

**the console** :

```
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.proces
```

the mongoose root file :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let isConnected: boolean = false


export const connectToDataBase = async () => {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true)


    if (!process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
        return console.log('missing MONGODB_URL');
    }
    if (isConnected) {
        return console.log('mongoDB is connected already !');
    }
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
            dbName: 'codeFlow',
        })
        isConnected = true
        console.log('mongoDb is connected');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('mongoDB connecttion failed', error);
        isConnected = false
    }
}
```

**the user model** :

```
import { Schema, model, models, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document {
    clerkId: string
    name: string
    username: string
    email: string
    password?: string
    bio?: string
    picture: string
    location?: string
    portfolioWebsite?: string
    reputaion?: number
    saved: Schema.Types.ObjectId[]
    joinAt: Date
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    clerkId: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, },
    bio: { type: String },
    picture: { type: String, required: true },
    location: { type: String },
    portfolioWebsite: { type: String },
    reputation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    saved: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
    joinAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

});


const User = models.User || model('User', UserSchema)

export default User
```

**the user action** :

```
import { Schema, model, models, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document {
    clerkId: string
    name: string
    username: string
    email: string
    password?: string
    bio?: string
    picture: string
    location?: string
    portfolioWebsite?: string
    reputaion?: number
    saved: Schema.Types.ObjectId[]
    joinAt: Date
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    clerkId: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, },
    bio: { type: String },
    picture: { type: String, required: true },
    location: { type: String },
    portfolioWebsite: { type: String },
    reputation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    saved: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }],
    joinAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

});


const User = models.User || model('User', UserSchema)

export default User
```

**the call of the `getUserById`** :
I used the userId from a dummy user I created in the database

```
import Question from "@/components/forms/Question"
import { getUserById } from "@/lib/actions/user.action"
import { auth } from "@clerk/nextjs"
import { redirect } from "next/navigation"


const Page = async () => {
  //const {userId} = auth()
  const userId = '123456'

  if (!userId) redirect('/sign-in')
  

  const mongoUser =  await getUserById({userId})

  console.log(mongoUser);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className=" h1-bold text-dark100_light900">Ask a question</h1>
      <div className="mt-8">
        <Question />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

**detailed console error** :

```
 ✓ Compiled in 308ms (870 modules)
connecting to mongoDB....
mongoDb is connected
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at t.useContext (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:162241)    at usePathname (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js:121:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:50)
    at au (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46505)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:58612
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59270
    at aA (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59278)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:6939)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at t.useContext (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:162241)    at usePathname (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js:121:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:50)
    at au (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46505)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:58612
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59270
    at aA (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59278)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:6939)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  page: '/ask-questions'
}
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
mongoDB connecttion failed Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.codeflow.ffodztu.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.codeflow.ffodztu.mongodb.net'
}
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at t.useContext (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:162241)    at usePathname (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js:121:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:50)
    at au (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46505)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:58612
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59270
    at aA (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59278)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:6939)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at t.useContext (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:162241)    at usePathname (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/navigation.js:121:34)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(ssr)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:161:50)
    at au (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:46505)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at ab (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
    at aw (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
    at a_ (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:58612
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59270
    at aA (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:59278)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:6939)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  page: '/ask-questions'
}
 ✓ Compiled in 1242ms (869 modules)
connecting to mongoDB....
 ✓ Compiled in 1655ms (869 modules)
connecting to mongoDB....
mongoDb is connected
mongoDB connecttion failed Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.codeflow.ffodztu.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.codeflow.ffodztu.mongodb.net'
}
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ○ Compiling /_error ...
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 655ms (1557 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 2.9s (1570 modules)
connecting to mongoDB....
connecting to mongoDB....
mongoDb is connected
 ⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
 ⨯ Internal error: MongooseError: Operation `users.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\saidPath\Next.js\next-dash\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:185:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
digest: "3887188482"
mongoDB connecttion failed Error: querySrv ETIMEOUT _mongodb._tcp.codeflow.ffodztu.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:275:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'querySrv',
  hostname: '_mongodb._tcp.codeflow.ffodztu.mongodb.net'
}
```

I expect to get user object with provided id !

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the error you're encountering could stem from the following reasons:

1. Ensure that your connection is active and operational.
2. Verify that your IP address has the necessary access permissions. You can do this by navigating to the "Data Services" tab, selecting "Security" on the left-hand side, and accessing "Network Access." From there, you can add your IP address and include "0.0.0.0/0" to grant access from any network address.